# How do I convert a Java executable into an APK to run it on Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am making my own mobile application in Java and I want to know if there exists a way to make an APK from it or I should start over in other lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

For Android you need to use the Android framework, but you can program this in Java or Kotlin. Download Android Studio and start with that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. There are other underlining files such as the manifest file and other codes that needs to be generated which only an android studio or a hybrid framework can do for you. Converting your code to an android app will be a process of creating a new app shell using android studio and reuse as much code as possible from your java based application.